# Filtering by `list<double>` column's element value range

Tags: cassandra

I'd like to filter rows of following table in cassandra.

```
CREATE TABLE mids_test_db.defect_data (
    wafer_id text,
    defect_id text,
    document_id text,
    fields list<double>,
    PRIMARY KEY (wafer_id, defect_id)
) 
...
CREATE INDEX defect_data_fields_idx ON mids_test_db.defect_data (values(fields));
```

What I firstly tried using something like `field[0] > 0.5` but failed.

```
cqlsh:mids_test_db> select fields from  defect_data where  wafer_id =  'MIDS_1_20170101_023000_30000_1548100671' and fields[0] > 0.5;
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Indexes on list entries (fields[index] = value) are not currently supported."
```

After searching google for a while, i'm feeling like this kind of job can not be easily done in Cassandra. The data model is something like a field value collection. mostly I want to query `defect` data using its `fields` data like above which is quite important in my business.

What approach should I have taken into consideration?. Application side filtering? Any hint or advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do directly with Cassandra, but you have following alternatives:

- if your Cassandra is DataStax Enterprise, then you can use [DSE Search](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/search/searchTOC.html);
- you can add an additional table to perform lookup:

(...ignore this line...)

```
CREATE TABLE mids_test_db.defect_data_lookup (
    wafer_id text,
    defect_id text,
    field double,
    PRIMARY KEY (wafer_id, field, defect_id)
);
```

after that you should be able to to do a range scan inside partition, and at least fetch the `defect_id` field, and fetch all field values via second query.

Depending on your Cassandra version, you may be able to use materialized view to maintain that lookup table for you.